# Clicking old list only shows last created id, should show the list-id im clicking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, ng-dialog

I have a dashboard where I can create lists and have them printed out on the dash, but when I click on either one of them it only opens up the one last created. What am I doing wrong? I am using the latest Angular, Firebase and AngularFire.

My code looks something like this, with create and open functions:

```
allLists = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + authData.uid);

// Modal service for creating a new list
   $scope.createList = function(){
        newList = allLists.push({
        name: 'new list'
      });
      listUID = newList.key();
      $rootScope.listUID = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + authData.uid + '/' + listUID);

      // Runs the ngDialog scheme with template etc
      ngDialog.open({
        template:'user-modal.html',
        controller: 'createController',
        scope: $scope,
        className:'ngdialog-theme-default'
      });
      console.log('listUID is: ' + listUID);
      return listUID;
    };

// Modal service for opening an old list for edit/remove/whatnot
   $scope.openList = function(index){
     oldUID = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + authData.uid + '/' + listUID);

     ngDialog.open({
       template: 'user-old-list.html',
       controller: 'oldListController',
       className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
       scope: $scope
      });
      console.log(listUID);
    };
```

With simple HTML as this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(id, lists) in listCounter" class="user-lists">
    <button ng-click="openList()" ng-model="listCounter[id]">{{lists.$id}}<br />{{lists.name}}</button>
 </div>
```

Which refers to:

```
 $rootScope.listCounter = $firebaseArray(allLists);
```

Comment: Can we see the full `ng-repeat` code?

Comment: @MuliYulzary 
`<div ng-repeat="(id, lists) in listCounter" class="user-lists">
     <button ng-click="openList()" ng-model="listCounter">{{lists.$id}}<br />{{lists.name}}</button>
  </div>`
Also:
`$rootScope.listCounter = $firebaseArray(allLists);`

Comment: can you edit the post so it'll be easier to read?

Comment: @MuliYulzary updated the post at the bottom! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `id` to `openList()`. try `ng-click="openList(id)"` in the template. also you are not refering to index anywhere in your function.

Comment: How and where should I refer to index?

Comment: If I set it like openList = function(id) it only points to the last created id, not the one I'm clicking on. :/

Comment: I don't have much experience with Firebase but in your `openList` in the controller. probably want to to change `oldUID = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/lists/' + authData.uid + '/' + listUID);` into some url specific to the list you want to show.

Comment: All the lists gets an unique id when they're created, and because of setting listUID in the createList function it's not available anywhere else, even though I made it global. It's not declared before a click and I don't know how to approach it, var listUID; or something similar doesn't work either.

Comment: From what I can see you initialize `listUID` everytime you create a new list and not keeping references to the old `listUID` so you're overwriting it with the newly created list `listUID`. You can try to push these into an array and access the correct `listUID` for each list by using the `index` in `openList(index)`

Comment: Edited my comment. check it out.

Comment: Push listUID into an array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110688/discussion-between-muli-yulzary-and-mtorn).